# Crystal Report ver 9:the remaining text does not appear to be part of the formula

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports

Here is a report that we have on Crystal ver 9. It includes parameters to select user id and dates of when they scan parts and provides the times when each part was scanned. What I would like it to add another column that calculates the interval times in between scans. The request is to have the first time stamp blank but the remaining calculate the interval times.

http://i59.tinypic.com/bjbtl1.jpg

This is sort of the mockup SQL I came up with in TOAD but I can't translate this into Crystal.

`with temptab as (
select 1 key, sysdate as dt from dual
union 
select 1 key, sysdate + interval '1' minute as dt from dual
union
select 1 key, sysdate + interval '2' minute as dt from dual
union
select 1 key, sysdate + interval '6' minute as dt from dual
union
select 1 key, sysdate + interval '7' minute as dt from dual
)
select t.key, t.dt, lag(t.dt) over (partition by t.key order by t.dt asc) prev_row_dt,
(t.dt - lag(t.dt) over (partition by t.key order by t.dt asc))*24*60*60 diff_in_seconds  from temptab t;`

---

Here is the CR  ihave for a randon user. Remember there are parameters set to select a user and date:

`SELECT "LOCN_HDR"."LOCN_BRCD", "ITEM_MASTER"."SKU_BRCD", "USER_MASTER"."LOGIN_USER_ID", "PROD_TRKG_TRAN"."MOD_DATE_TIME", "PROD_TRKG_TRAN"."TRAN_TYPE", "PROD_TRKG_TRAN"."TRAN_CODE", "PROD_TRKG_TRAN"."USER_ID", "USER_MASTER"."USER_NAME", "PROD_TRKG_TRAN"."NBR_UNITS", "PROD_TRKG_TRAN"."SKU_ID"
FROM   "PKMS"."LOCN_HDR" "LOCN_HDR", "PKMS"."USER_MASTER" "USER_MASTER", "PKMS"."PROD_TRKG_TRAN" "PROD_TRKG_TRAN", "PKMS"."ITEM_MASTER" "ITEM_MASTER"
WHERE  ("USER_MASTER"."LOGIN_USER_ID"="PROD_TRKG_TRAN"."USER_ID") AND ("LOCN_HDR"."LOCN_ID"="PROD_TRKG_TRAN"."TO_LOCN") AND ("PROD_TRKG_TRAN"."SKU_ID"="ITEM_MASTER"."SKU_ID") AND ("PROD_TRKG_TRAN"."TRAN_CODE"='001' OR "PROD_TRKG_TRAN"."TRAN_CODE"='005') AND ("PROD_TRKG_TRAN"."TRAN_TYPE"='200' OR "PROD_TRKG_TRAN"."TRAN_TYPE"='300') AND ("PROD_TRKG_TRAN"."MOD_DATE_TIME">={ts '2014-04-16 00:00:00'} AND "PROD_TRKG_TRAN"."MOD_DATE_TIME"<{ts '2014-04-17 00:00:00'}) AND "PROD_TRKG_TRAN"."USER_ID"='4517'
ORDER BY "PROD_TRKG_TRAN"."MOD_DATE_TIME", "USER_MASTER"."LOGIN_USER_ID", "PROD_TRKG_TRAN"."TRAN_TYPE`

Comment: What's the question here? How does your title (A CR error message) fit in?

Comment: The question is how can I calculate the time interval? When I plug in the code fro mmy original question that error is what I get

Comment: All I'm seeing is SQL... what is the Crystal Reports formula you've been working on to calculate the interval (the one that is giving the error message)?

Comment: I guess that's the thing. How do I translate the first SQL in crystal. The first SQL statement is what I came up with using TOAD.

Comment: {PROD_TRKG_TRAN.TRAN_CODE} in ["001", "005"] and
{PROD_TRKG_TRAN.TRAN_TYPE} in ["200", "300"] and
{PROD_TRKG_TRAN.MOD_DATE_TIME} = {?Date} and
{PROD_TRKG_TRAN.USER_ID} = {?User}

Answer (score 0):

Any filter type information would go into the Report --> Selection Formula --> Record

Then in the details section you would place a formula field to find the difference that you are looking for and it would look something like this

```
datediff("s",date(totext({Calibration.C2301}&' '&{Calibration.C2333})),{Calibration.C2335})
```

I'm not sure what the lag(t.dt) is but the above is the basic syntax the date(totext({Calibration.C2301}&' '&{Calibration.C2333})) is a date field and time field concatenated make this work.

Comment: {PROD_TRKG_TRAN.TRAN_CODE} in ["001", "005"] and
{PROD_TRKG_TRAN.TRAN_TYPE} in ["200", "300"] and
{PROD_TRKG_TRAN.MOD_DATE_TIME} = {?Date} and
{PROD_TRKG_TRAN.USER_ID} = {?User}